# Let $G$ be a group, $H\unlhd G$, prove that the commutator subgroup $H'$ of $H$ is a normal subgroup in $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, derived-subgroup

Let $G$ be a group, $H$, a normal subgroup of $G$, prove that the commutator subgroup $H'$ of $H$ is a normal subgroup in $G$.

My ideas:

I want to prove it like this: $gH'g^{-1} = H'$  $\forall g \in G$ but I don't know how to continue, because $g$ may not lie in $H$ and $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$ it's not a commutator.

Comment: This is a special case of a more general statement: if $H$ is normal in $G$ and $C< H$ is a characteristic subgroup of $H$, then $C$ is normal in $G$. (A subgroup of $H$ is called characteristic if it is preserved by all automorphisms of $H$.)

Comment: In fact, commutator subgroups are verbal, which implies they are fully invariant, which implies they are characteristic. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4099663/742).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $g[h_1,h_2]g^{-1}=[gh_1g^{-1}, gh_2g^{-1}]$. Why is this a commutator of $H$?

Comment: Thanks, I got it